# On a condition in real linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

For me $a,c\in[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$ is small (say $0.01$).

Is it possible to set this condition

$$c\leq\max\bigg(\frac{(a-\epsilon)}{(1-\epsilon)}, 0\bigg)$$

in real linear program?

This does not work $$\frac{(a-\epsilon)}{(1-\epsilon)}\leq d$$
$$0\leq d$$
$$c\leq d.$$

Essentially I want $d=0$ if $\frac{(a-\epsilon)}{(1-\epsilon)}<0$ else set $d=\frac{(a-\epsilon)}{(1-\epsilon)}$ and set $c\leq d$ which is equivalent to $c\leq d$ where $d=0$ if $a<\epsilon$ else $d=\frac{(a-\epsilon)}{(1-\epsilon)}$. How do I do that?

Comment: See https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/

Comment: @YukiJ how do you penalize  S^- and S^+ in a real linear program?

Comment: Only way seems to be $bS^-   +  (1-b)S^+$ where $b\in\{0,1\}$ which maked it MILP and not a real linear program.

Comment: what are the variables in this constraint?

Comment: @LinAlg only $a,c$ are variables $\epsilon$ is fixed.

Comment: @Robut that is indeed the only way because the constraint is not convex in $y$. The link of YukiJ is inappropriate for linear optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nonlinear constraint
$$x\leq\max\bigg(\frac{y-\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}, 0\bigg)$$
where $x,y$ are variables and $\epsilon$ is a parameter, cannot be represented with purely linear constraints since it is not convex. You need an extra binary variable $z$ that indicates which of the two terms in the max is active, and a prespecified upper bound $M$ on the absolute value of the first term of the max expression. Then you can state this problem as:
$$\begin{align}x &\leq \frac{y-\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} + zM \\
x &\leq 0 + (1-z)M \\
z &\in \{0,1\}. \end{align}$$