# piecewise linear constraints and equivalent linear constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749811/on-a-condition-in-real-linear-programming)$^{[1]}$ question and [this](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/)$^{[2]}$ post, I'm interested in rewriting piecewise linear constraints as equivalent sets of linear constraints in the context of an LP. In the following, let $x,y$ be scalar decision variables and let $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

---

Consider the piecewise linear constraint
$$\max\{x,0\} \leq c \tag{1}$$
Can we rewrite (1) as the pair of constraints 
$$x \leq c,\quad 0 \leq c \tag{$1^*$}$$
I.e., are ($1$) and ($1^*$) equivalent?

---

Also, this reference [[2]](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/) confused me. Here the author express
$$\max\{x,0\} \geq c \tag{$2$}$$ 
as
\begin{align}
c \geq x + |x - y|, \quad
c \geq y + |x - y|
\end{align}
(before breaking down the absolute values into penalized linear constraints). This led me to a few questions:

1. can we reverse the inequality in ($2$) to get it in a form equivalent to ($1$) where the author's reformulation works?
2. why does $|x-y|$ come in? the author's translation between $\min$ and $\max$ feels circular, so there must be something I'm missing...
3. if ($1$) and ($1^*$) are not equivalent, is the reason due to no penalty (I'm assuming that the penalty should be added to the objective, kinda like an exact penalty method)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) and (1*) are equivalent.

In the second part you messed something up with the formulas. You can write (2) as

$$
\begin{array}{l}
x=x^+-x^-\\
x^+,x^-\geq 0\\
c\leq x^+
\end{array}
$$

as long as you ensure that at most one of $x^+,x^-$ is nonzero. That you can do with a binary variable. In general you cannot linearize it completely because $\max(x,0)$ is not concave.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it that concavity specifically is needed? Is it the direction of the inequality that necessitates concavity vs convexity?

Comment: @jjjjjj If you can express the set $c\leq f(x)$ using linear constraints (or as a convex optimization problem in general) then you showed $f$ is concave.

Comment: Aren’t linear constraints both concave and convex though? Why just concave? I’m missing something

Comment: @jjjjjj Theorem $f:R\to R$ is concave if and only if the hypograph $\{(x,y)~:~y\leq f(x)\}$ is a convex set. So: if you can describe the hypograph with linear constraints, then it follows it is a convex set, hence $f$ is concave. But your $f$ isn't.

Comment: Ahh, so it's just that $(2)$ is not a convex constraint (in $x$) because its feasible set is not convex. Makes sense, thanks. So I'm still confused about what the author in [{2}](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/) is doing with $x \leq \max(a,b)$... Is it clear to you?

Comment: @jjjjjj Not really. It is a bit messy in [2]

Comment: Cool, ok, maybe it's just a bit imprecise and not worth digging into w/o further direction from the author

Comment: Any chance you'd have time to help me think about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797042/linearize-a-sum-of-linear-and-piecewise-linear-functions) Q??