# linearize a sum of linear and piecewise linear functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

How can I linearize the following constraint:
$$
c_1\max(y + |x| - d_1, 0) + c_2\max(y + |x| - d_2, 0) + e - y \leq 0 \tag{$*$}
$$
where $x,y$ are scalar decision variables, and $c_i, d_i, e \geq 0$?

I believe the following is correct and would appreciate confirmation
\begin{align}
c_1(y+|x| - d_1) + c_2(y + |x| - d_2) + e - y \leq 0 \\
c_1(y+|x| - d_1) + e - y \leq 0 \\
c_2(y + |x| - d_2) + e - y \leq 0 \\
e - y \leq 0
\end{align}

Comment: How about adding one more constraint, $e-y \leq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct. At the end you can observe that each of your constraints boils down to $|x|\leq s$, where $s$ is some linear combination of other stuff, and that you can write as $s\geq x, s\geq -x$.