# Linear optimization with max function in constraint

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

I have a linear optimization:

$$ \min_{x_i} -\sum_i x_i $$
$$ \mathrm{s.t.} Ax \le b$$

Where $x$ is a variable vector. I would like to introduce into the linear problem an additional constraint that include the $max$ functions, like this:

$$ \max_i (x_i) + \max_i (-x_i)\le c$$

where $c$ is a given constant. Is there a way to incorporate that constrain keep the linear formulation of the problem?

Thanks in advance for any help or references!

I want something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2447498/432476), but in my case the max function is in the constraint and not in the optimization function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constraint is equivalent to:
$$\max_i x_i - \min_i x_i \leq c$$

You can rewrite it with two more variables $\max X$ and $\min X$ and a linear number of constraints:

$$\max X \geq x_i\;\;\forall i$$
$$ \min X \leq x_i\;\;\forall i$$
$$\max X-\min X \leq c$$